# Api gateway implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-apicontroller

What's the way to expose microservices endpoints from API gateway? does API gateway have a knowledge about the services domain objects?

Say, i have `order` service exposing `/api/order`, `/api/order/{orderId}`, etc. with domain object `Order`. The api gateway define `OrderController` (with example action below) which routes request to `order` service,

```
1. IActionResult Post([FromBody]object obj) { }
2. IActionResult Post([FromBody]Order order) { }
```

#2 has to know about `Order` object, whereas #1 doesn't. #2 simplify api documentation (i.e `swagger`), but couple the gateway with the service models.

what's the best way to go about exposing the services endpoints?

Comment: Use different gateway and service models.

Comment: hi @Amy can you elaborate more?

Comment: You noted the disadvantage to #2 is it couples your gateway to the service models.  Using different models and mapping between them decouples them.